# Tab dont work well when I use linux screen in ConEmu?

Tags: gnu-screen, conemu

ConEmu version preview-191012. Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06.

I connect to remote machine and attach to screen in ConEmu.

If I press 'tab' to autocomplete filename, the cursor will move half of screen.

If I do above action in powershell, the 'tab' work well.

Comment: Hard to believe. The ConEmu does not do autocompletion, it just passes the `Tab` keypress to console. So the behavior is expected to be the same. Check thoroughly which remote client you are using in **both** cases.